# Javascript page keeps refreching upon updated data

Tags: javascript, leaflet, real-time

I've written a simple html page that displays gps coordinates on a map. I am using leaflet to show the map and the markers. The data is a json file that updates multiple times a seconds. My javascript program checks every 1 second if the file has changed. If it has it should update the coordinates on the screen. Previously it worked correctly on occasions. But recently I've gotten a new error. Whenever the update occurs the website has an error and has to refresh, removing all the previous data displayed. The error i get from the console this [image: exception from website].
This error comes from the `leaflet.js` file. Which i have no access to.
Am i doing something incorrectly? I am thankful for any support.
Here are the javascript and js files:

```js
var map = L.map('mymap').setView([45.5937, 13.9629], 5);
var ourData = [];

var markers = [];
var polyline;

var boat_pos_markers = [];
var nr_bpm;
var boat_pos_layer = [];


L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors',
  maxZoom: 20,
  minZoom: 2,
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);


// Reads Waypoints from file and draws markers and lines to map
document.querySelector(".load-waypoint-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  var waypoints = document.getElementById('output').textContent;


  waypoints = waypoints.replaceAll('{', '');
  waypoints = waypoints.replaceAll('}', '');
  waypoints = waypoints.replaceAll('\n', '');

  split_waypoints = waypoints.split(",");

  var nr_waypoints = split_waypoints.length - 1;
  var waypoint_half = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < nr_waypoints; i++) {
    var pos = new L.LatLng(split_waypoints[i], split_waypoints[i + 1]);
    markers.push(pos);
    i++;
  }

  polyline = new L.polyline(markers, {
    color: 'blue'
  });
  polyline.addTo(map);

  waypoint_half = 0;
  var i = 0;
  // Here's where you iterate over the array of coordinate objects.
  markers.forEach(function(coord) {
    var circle = L.circle(coord, {
      color: 'blue',
      fillColor: '#0000A0',
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      radius: 11.12 // 8500 
    }).bindPopup(`<p> ${split_waypoints[i]} ${split_waypoints[i + 1]} <p> ${"Waypoint: "} ${waypoint_half++} </h3>`).on('click').addTo(map);
    i += 2;
  });

  // zoom the map to the polyline
  map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
})

// Connects Serial device (Arduino)
document.querySelector(".connect-serial-btn").addEventListener('click', async() => {
  // if ("serial" in navigator) {
  //     // The Web Serial API is supported.
  //     alert("Serial is supported");
  // }
  // else
  //     alert("Serial is NOT supported")


  // const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
  // await port.open({ baudRate: 9600 });
  // const reader = port.readable.getReader();

  // async function readSerial() {
  //   while (true) {
  //     const { value, done } = await reader.read();
  //     if (done) {
  //       console.log("Reader has been canceled.");
  //       break;
  //     }
  //     console.log("Read:", new TextDecoder().decode(value));
  //   }
  // }

  // readSerial();
  alert("Not functional");

})

// Center to Boat
document.querySelector(".center-boat-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  var points = [boat_pos_markers.at(nr_bpm - 3), boat_pos_markers.at(nr_bpm - 2), boat_pos_markers.at(nr_bpm - 1)];
  map.fitBounds(points);
})

// User selects file to read
function showSelectedFile() {
  selectedfile.value = document.getElementById("inputfile").value;

}
document.getElementById('inputfile')
  .addEventListener('change', function() {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('output')
        .textContent = fr.result;
    }
    fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
  })

// Resets view to center of waypoints
document.querySelector(".center-map-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());

});

// Deletes boats lines
document.querySelector(".clear-boat-line-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  boat_pos_layer.forEach(function(item) {
    map.removeLayer(item)
  });
});

function parseData() {
  data = document.getElementById('output').textContent;
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(data);
  // // Parse GPS 
  var lat = data.Lat;
  var lon = data.Lon;
  var pos = new L.LatLng(lat, lon);
  boat_pos_markers.push(pos);
  nr_bpm = boat_pos_markers.length;
  var points = [boat_pos_markers.at(nr_bpm - 2), boat_pos_markers.at(nr_bpm - 1)];
  boat_pos_layer.push(L.polyline(points, {
    color: 'red'
  }).addTo(map));

  // Parse Boat dir
  var boat_dir = data.Dir;
  // Parse Wind dir
  var wind_dir = data.Wind_dir;
  updateAngle(boat_dir, wind_dir);
}

function updateAngle(boat_dir, wind_dir) {
  var boat = parseInt(boat_dir);
  var wind = parseInt(wind_dir);
  var data = [{
    angle: (wind - 90) % 360,
    color: 'blue'
  }, {
    angle: (boat - 90) % 360,
    color: 'red'
  }];

  paths = svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(data);

  paths.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', path_d)
    .merge(paths)
    .style('fill', d => d.color)
    .attr('transform', d => `rotate(${d.angle})`);

  paths.exit().remove();
}

// Sim Update  ---------------------------------------------
const pickButton = document.querySelector('button#pick');
const stopButton = document.querySelector('button#stop');

let selected, i;
let pollRate = 1; // seconds

pickButton.addEventListener('click', accessFile);
stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopWatching);

async function accessFile() {
  stopWatching();

  let [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();

  if (fileHandle) {
    let f = await fileHandle.getFile();
    if (!f) {
      console.log('failed accessing file');
      return;
    }
    selected = {
      handle: fileHandle,
      file: f
    };
    console.log('selected', f);
    readFile(f);
    startWatching();
  } else {
    console.log('no file selected');
  }
}

async function checkFile() {
  if (!selected) {
    return;
  }
  let f = await selected.handle.getFile();
  if (f.lastModified > selected.file.lastModified) {
    console.log(selected.file.name, 'was updated');
    selected.file = f;
    readFile(f);
  } else {
    console.log(selected.file.name, 'had no changes');
  }
}

function readFile(f) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', event => {
    console.log(event.target.result);
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = event.target.result;
  });
  reader.readAsText(f);
}

function startWatching() {
  if (i) {
    clearInterval(i);
  }
  stopButton.disabled = false;
  i = setInterval(async ts => {
    if (!selected) {
      return;
    }
    checkFile();
    // parseData();
  }, pollRate * 1000);
}

function stopWatching() {
  clearInterval(i);
  i = null;
  selected = null;
  stopButton.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div id="mymap"></div>

  <div id="compass">
    <script>
      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr("height", 200)
        .attr('viewBox', '-50 -50 100 100')
        .attr("id", "compass")

      var path_d = "M 0,0 L 0,-10 L 50,0 L 0,10 Z";
    </script>
  </div>

  <div class="button-group flex-style">
    <div class="component1">
      <button class="center-map-btn"> Center Map </button>
    </div>
    <div class="component2">
      <button class="center-boat-btn"> Center Boat </button>
    </div>
    <div class="component3">
      <button class="load-waypoint-btn"> Load Waypoints </button>
    </div>
    <div class="component4">
      <button class="connect-serial-btn"> Connect Serial </button>
    </div>
    <div class="component5">
      <button class="clear-boat-line-btn"> Clear Boat Line </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="file-group">
    <pre id="output"></pre>
    <input id='selectedfile' type='text' name='selectedfile'>
    <input id='inputfile' type='file' name='inputfile' onChange='showSelectedFile()'>

    <button id="pick"> Pick File </button>
    <button id="stop" disabled> Stop Watching </button>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

I've tried changing my input format from strings to json files. Thinking it was a formatting issue.
I've tried disabling any part of the code that had an influence with the data. So theoretically it shouldn't be caused by my code.
Even if i have no file selected to listen. The error still occurs.

Comment: That error is inside a [try-catch block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), and it's safe t ignore it.

Comment: Ah its good to know its not something important. But the webpage keeps refreshing, is there a way i can stop that?

Comment: I suggest you should make sure of what "pause on caught exceptions" means, and narrow down the problem. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example